# SQL statements on a Geodatabase

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-engine, sql

I have converted a shapefile into a geodatabase which I use for geocoding via the ILocator interface.  It has the extension (.mdb) and contains address fields with a point which is stored as a long binary object (I think).  I have queried it directory using libraries like OleDB. I'm wondering if there's a way to do a `SELECT * FROM mytable` using the ArcEngine interfaces.

I'll provide some context as well.  I'm trying to get around the inflexibility of the [SoundEx implementation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7368/configure-soundex-in-arcengine) and some limitations with the locator styles. The locator style interace works like this for address search results:

```
IField addressField = candidateFields.get_Field(fieldIndex);
```

But the fields returned only match the fields in the locator, so I get "Zone" and not city, state, zip, unit number, owner name, parcel price, etc.

Comment: If performance is a key, I'd use file geodatabase (stored in a folder with a .gdb extension).  I don't think you'd be able to use OleDB with a file gdb though.  Are you following [this example](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//00010000038r000000)?

Comment: @Kirk Kuykendall Yeah I'm using that example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be misreading your question, but if you are indeed trying to query the table directly, you can create a QueryFilter and set the SubFields property to include all of the fields you need in the returned cursor.

Comment: I suspect he is trying to get to normal SQL functions that you just can't do in the ArcObjects world. Maybe I am wrong...

Answer (score 3):

No, the ArcEngine/ArcObjects APIs all wrap the Datalayer to support the GIS functions for the common classes. Your best option is to create a class in your development language to perform your Query/Search logic natively and if needed return those results and cast them into a ESRI format.

You will also find this is fast as you won't have the direct overhead of the ArcObjects calls wrapping everything you do.